# A question about Narasimhan-Seshadri Donaldson theorem.

Tags: connections, holomorphic-bundles

I see a statement of the theorem in [Jonathan Evans' lecture note 13](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/YM-lectures/lecture13.pdf)

> An indecomposable Hermitian holomorphic vector bundle $\mathcal E$ on
>   a Riemann surface $M$ is stable if and only if there is a compatible
>   unitary connection on $\mathcal E$ with constant central cervature 
>   $$\star F_\nabla=-2\pi i\mu(\mathcal E)$$

Some notations: $F_\nabla$ is the curvature of the connection $\nabla$, $\mu(\mathcal E)=\frac{c_1(\mathcal E)}{\text{rank}(\mathcal E)}$ is the slope of $\mathcal E$.

Now I do not understand the statement, because from Atiyah & Bott's paper, *The Yang-Mills Equations over Riemann Surfaces* [sec 5](http://yangmills%20equations%20over%20riemann%20surfaces), we can identify the space of all unitary connection on $E$ and that of all holomorphic structures over $E$, where $E$ is the underlying complex vector bundle of $\mathcal E$. So now we are given a holomorphic structure $\mathcal E$, I think the unitary connection is uniquely determined. So is this theorem telling us that this unique-determined connection has this property?

Comment: Well actually Atiyah-Bott's statement is for a Hermitian vector bundle, while a holomorphic bundle $E$ could admit different Hermitian metrics to get different connections, see 2.1.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08122.pdf and it may be helpful.